# Export all Azure AD groups and their members (PowerShell)

Tags: azure, powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory, office365

I have seen many threads on exporting groups and getting members, but strangely not both. Basically I need a .csv file or similar with every AD group and its corresponding members.

I believe it needs to be done from Azure as we have multiple domains and Office 365/incloud groups (Azure AD has all of these listed).

So I don't think there is another way to export our groups to a single CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This PowerShell script should return you what you are looking for in CSV format (one line for each group/member value).

```
$groups=Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
ForEach ($group in $groups){
    $members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true
    ForEach ($member in $members){
        Write-output $group.DisplayName "," $member.ObjectId "," $member.ObjectType $member.UserType "," $member.UserPrincipalName >> C:\scripts\output.csv
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome that seemed to gather all the groups and members. Thanks heaps. But where does it export the csv too? Also would it be possible to have a similar cmd that just gets the owner of the group? Sorry I am a massive powershell noob

Comment: The output is printed on the screen. I will edit the answer in order to write the output to disk.

Comment: Awesome thanks again L M, much appreciated. How would I modify this to just get the owners?

Comment: I figure it out actually,                                                                                                         $groups=Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
ForEach ($group in $groups){
    $Owners = Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true 
    ForEach ($Owner in $Owners){ 
        Write-output $group.DisplayName "," $Owner.ObjectId "," $Owner.ObjectType $Owner.UserType "," $Owner.UserPrincipalName >> C:\scripts\Owner.csv
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

I have tweaked the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58828015/export-all-azure-ad-groups-and-their-members-powershell/58829041#58829041) a little for a different output format.

```
Connect-AzureAD
$groups=Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
$resultsarray =@()
ForEach ($group in $groups){
    $members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true 
    ForEach ($member in $members){
       $UserObject = new-object PSObject
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "Group Name" -Value $group.DisplayName
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "Member Name" -Value $member.DisplayName
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "ObjType" -Value $member.ObjectType
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "UserType" -Value $member.UserType
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "UserPrincipalName" -Value $member.UserPrincipalName
       $resultsarray += $UserObject
    }
}
$resultsarray | Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8  -Delimiter ";" -Path "C:\scripts\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```