# Export all Azure AD groups, including nested groups, their members and owners (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-powershell-v2

What would be a PowerShell script to export all Azure AD groups, their members and owners into one CSV file?

I also need an expanded nested groups.

Comment: Will this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58828015/export-all-azure-ad-groups-and-their-members-powershell

Answer (score 4):

Here is something I came up with. It should work as long as you have the [AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) PowerShell module.

```
function get-recursivegroupmembers {
    param($grouplistname, $currgroup, $groupmemtype)
    $members = if ($groupmemtype -eq "owner") {get-azureadgroupowner -ObjectId $currgroup.ObjectId -All $true} else {get-azureadgroupmember -ObjectId $currgroup.ObjectId -All $true}
    $grouptype = "Distribution Group"
    if ($currgroup.SecurityEnabled -eq $true)
    {
        $grouptype = "Security Group"
    }

    foreach ($member in $members)
    {
        if($member.ObjectType -eq "Group" )
        {
            get-recursivegroupmembers "$grouplistname->$($member.DisplayName)" $member $groupmemtype
        }
        else
        {
            Add-Content -Path $filename -Value "$grouplistname,$grouptype,$groupmemtype,$($member.ObjectId),$($member.ObjectType) $($member.UserType),$($member.UserPrincipalName)"
        }
    }
}

Connect-AzureAD
$filename = ".\groupusers-$(get-date -f 'ddMMyyyy-HHmmss').csv"
$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
Add-Content -Path $filename -Value "Group(s),Group Type,Member Type,User ObjectId,AAD Object Type,UPN"

ForEach ($group in $groups)
{
    get-recursivegroupmembers $group.DisplayName $group "owner"
    get-recursivegroupmembers $group.DisplayName $group "member"
}
```

This will give you a file in the current folder where the script is. Called groupusers, the first field will contain the group and if it's a nested group member it would show like group->nestedgroup, owner or member, etc.

Comment: Awesome @alphaz!
I was trying to modify the script with SecurityEnabled and variables for time but no luck :(
...

Comment: ```
param($grouplistname, $currgroupid, $groupmemtype, $grouptype)
    $grouptype = if($grouptype.SecurityEnabled -eq $true) {"Security Group"} else {"Distribition Group"}
```
and 
```
{ add-content -Path $filename -Value "$grouplistname,$groupmemtype,$grouptype,$($member.ObjectId),$($member.ObjectType) $($member.UserType),$($member.UserPrincipalName)" }
    }
$filename = ".\AADGroupsMembersOwners_$(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss).csv"
```

Comment: I changed the script somewhat, it has your edits in it now

Answer (score 0):

Sorry couldn't comment as I don't have enough rep, I created an account to thank you Peter.

This worked a treat. I had tried multiple other articles but this one works. All I did was to target groups with a specific naming scheme was change this line and remove $true as that said 'a positional parameter cannot be found that accepts the argument True'

```
$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "File Share"
```

That then searches for any group starting with 'File Share'