# Overwrite CSV file in SharePoint with Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I want to save results of listing AAD users into csv file located in SharePoint.
I have AAD users in multpile nested AAD groups and to list them I am using the script proposed by @alphaz18 in this thread:
[Export all Azure AD groups, including nested groups, their members and owners (PowerShell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61809720/export-all-azure-ad-groups-including-nested-groups-their-members-and-owners-p)

However, now I would like to move the script away from my local drive, so I'm wondering if it is possible to export the results directly to a SharePoint folder?

**The perfect solution would be if I could overwrite the Sharepoint file every time I run the code, but despite many attempts, I couldn't solve these two issues:

- change how csv file is created in above code written by @alphaz18 from Add-Content to Export-CSV -Force (to overwrite current csv)
- save the csv with the list of users directly to a folder in Sharepoint (avoiding saving to local disk)**

I found information about PnP.Powershell Module, but most of the solutions save csv file locally then export it to SharePoint. For example I tried to make the following changes in the @alphaz18 code:

```
function get-recursivegroupmembers {
    param($grouplistname, $currgroup, $groupmemtype)
    $members = if ($groupmemtype -eq "owner") {get-azureadgroupowner -ObjectId $currgroup.ObjectId -All $true} else {get-azureadgroupmember -ObjectId $currgroup.ObjectId -All $true}
    $grouptype = "Distribution Group"
    $result = @()
    if ($currgroup.SecurityEnabled -eq $true)
    {
        $grouptype = "Security Group"
    }

    foreach ($member in $members)
    {
        if($member.ObjectType -eq "Group" )
        {
            get-recursivegroupmembers "$grouplistname->$($member.DisplayName)" $member $groupmemtype
        }
        else
        {
            $result += $($member.ObjectId) + "," + $($member.ObjectType) + "," +  $($member.UserType) + "," + $($member.UserPrincipalName) + "," + $($member.DisplayName)  + "," + $($member.Department) + "," +  $($member.MailNickName) 
        }
    }
}

Connect-AzureAD

$location = "<SharePoint website address>"
Connect-PnPOnline $location -Interactive


$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString '<Main AAD Group>'


ForEach ($group in $groups)
{
    get-recursivegroupmembers $group.DisplayName $group "owner"
    get-recursivegroupmembers $group.DisplayName $group "member"
}
$result | Export-CSV -Path "$location\aadgroupmembers.csv" -Force
```

but I failed both for Export-CSV and PNP connection..

Is it possible to update csv files directly on Sharepoint?